# Json sent by xamarin has no data at end

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I am trying to send the following JSON file to the web API I created. But, the API is working fine and sending no data and not taking the data from the sent JSON file. While it is being able to take data from postman sent JSON file.

I have tried using the ToString() method with the JSON object and also tried postman to verify if my API is working fine. The API seems to work properly with postman send JSON file but the file sent by the Xamarin forms is sending no data in the JSON file or something and database get no data in it.

There are no errors being shown but the data is not being uploaded to the database please do help me to get this done faster.

coding is below,

```
public async void check2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var post = new poster {user=username.Text, pass=password.Text};

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(post);

        var content = new StringContent(json,Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var response = httpClient.PostAsync("http://licapi.witlyf.com/api/values", content);

        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new navigator(username.Text));

    }
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: The code is in MainPage.xaml.cs of the app and the web api is hosted online on a server. The get request is executed perfectly and login is working well but for signup test I used the above code and the code ran but the database gets blank values for username and password as if jaon dod not sent any data.

Comment: @ShubhamKumbhar Which device platforms (and API levels) are you using as `http` is not directly supported unless you add exceptions to your app to allow the OS to accept non-trusted networking calls.

Comment: have you verified that `content` contains the correct json?  Have you verified that your server is receiving the request?  Have you checked the error logs on the server?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the content contains the right JSON file. I did check logs and it says code 204 in the logs for all the post requests executed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been met it seems I have put my JSON file variable names to be different than in web API so when I made the same the link worked the data was submitted to the database.